# format () : ValueError: Precision not allowed in integer format specifier

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am a python newbie.I am just getting acquainted with format method.

From a book that I am reading to learn python

```
What Python does in the format method is that it substitutes each argument
value into the place of the specification. There can be more detailed specifications
such as:
decimal (.) precision of 3 for float '0.333'
>>> '{0:.3}'.format(1/3)
fill with underscores (_) with the text centered
(^) to 11 width '___hello___'
>>> '{0:_^11}'.format('hello')
keyword-based 'Swaroop wrote A Byte of Python'
>>> '{name} wrote {book}'.format(name='Swaroop', book='A Byte of Python')
```

In the python interpreter if I try

```
print('{0:.3}'.format(1/3))
```

It gives the error

```
 File "", line 24, in 
ValueError: Precision not allowed in integer format specifier
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To print the floating point numbers, you have to have atleast one of the inputs as floats, like this

```
print('{0:.3}'.format(1.0/3))
```

If both the inputs are integers to the division operator, the returned result will also be in int, with the decimal part truncated.

**Output**

```
0.333
```

You can convert the data to float with `float` function, like this

```
data = 1
print('{0:.3}'.format(float(data) / 3))
```

Comment: what does '{0:.3} mean? how does format substitute for these values?

Comment: @liv2hak, 0 is the first argument in the format function..  The colon is just a separator between the data element getting passed in and the formatting.  .3 is telling it to format it with 3 characters to the right of the decimal.

Answer (score 13):

It's better to add `f`:

```
In [9]: print('{0:.3f}'.format(1/3))
0.000
```

in this way you could notice that `1/3` gives an **integer** and then correct that to `1./3` or `1/3.` .

Answer (score 5):

It is worth noting that this error will only happen in python 2.  In python 3, division always returns a float.

You can replicate this with the `from __future__ import division` statement in python 2.

```
~$ python
Python 2.7.6 
>>> '{0:.3}'.format(1/3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Precision not allowed in integer format specifier
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> '{0:.3}'.format(1/3)
'0.333'
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python3 `fstring` Examples:

### Decimals

```py
# Set the Result to a variable:
a = 1/3
# Format the result :.3f is the length of the digits "AFTER" the decial point.
print(f"{a:.3f}")
# Returns: 0.333

print(f"{a:.6f}")
# Returns: 0.333333

print(f"{a:.32f}")
# Returns: 0.33333333333333331482961625624739

print(f"{a:.50f}")
# Returns: 0.33333333333333331482961625624739099293947219848633

print(f"{a:.55f}")
# Returns: 0.3333333333333333148296162562473909929394721984863281250

# # NOTE: this does round see the difference between the ending of .50 & .55
```

### Digits & Decimals

```py
# You can do the same for leading zeros:
a = (1/3) + 145630

print(f"{a:016.03f}")

# Returns 000000145630.333

# if you don't want to lead with Zeros and just spaces.
print(f"{a:16.03f}")
# Returns "      145630.333"
# # NOTE: 
# With this one - notice there are only 12 Digits/Spaces Left of the decimal.

print(f"{a:016.55f}")
# Returns 145630.3333333333430346101522445678710937500000000000000000000
# # NOTE:
# will never show leading spaces or zeros
# as the decimal digit count is greater than the total digit count.

# So the way to calculate it what will properly be displayed is:
# `f"{VARIABLE:(TOTALDIGITS).(DECIMALDIGITS)f}"`
# Total Digits - Decimal Digits - 1 (for the decimal point)
# If the return from the equasion above is < 1 
# # There will never be a leading digit/space.  
# As shown in the last example of Digits & Decimals.  (16-55-1) =
# "-40"  So no Leading digits will ever show.
```

### Digits Only

```py
# If you only need to update formats for Digits and no Decimals:
a = 148
print(f"{a:016d}")
# or
print(f"{a:016.0f}")

# Returns 0000000000000148

print(f"{a:16d}")
# or 
print(f"{a:16.0f}")
# Returns "             148"
```

### Exceptions to Note:

```py
a = 148.15
print(f"{a:16d}")  # THROWS AN ERROR:
# ValueError: Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'float'

# or 
print(f"{a:16.0f}")
# Returns "             148"
# # NOTE: This TRUNCATES YOUR DECIMAL FORMAT.
```